# Rails form validation works in one template but not another for the same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, validation, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Another hair-puller. AFter two days of fighting with this I cannot figure out what is wrong here.

Basically I have a form validation triggered by the model:

```
validates :user, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :on => :create
validates :passwordHash, :presence => true, :confirmation => true, :on => :create
```

The user not being empty works on the update form View:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|      
  = f.input :user
  = f.input :locale
  = f.input :localeLanguage, :label => 'Language', :as => :select, :collection => $language_array 
  = f.input :moderator
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :passwordHash, :label => 'Password'
```

But not on the new users View:

```
  = simple_form_for @user do |f|  
    %table.table-condensed
      %tr
        %td
          =f.input :user, :label => false, :placeholder => 'username'
      %tr
        %td
          = f.input :passwordHash, :label => false, :placeholder => 'password'
      %tr
        %td
          = f.input :email, :label => false, :placeholder => 'email'
      %tr
        %td
          = f.submit "Create User", :class => 'btn btn-primary'
```

The only difference I can see between these views is that the first one has sessions created since a user has already logged in, the second one doesn't. But as far as I know this should not make a difference. Of course, the `update` form does have an actual @user object whereas in the `new` one it is empty. But I've seen Ryan Bates' railscast of a new user validation and he does pretty much the same thing.

What happens is the `users#create` action being invoked after submitting the form with empty values (which should not be possible). Of course I get an error because the `passwordHash` is empty.

I should point out that I'm not using any extra gems to aid in password confirmation (in the railscast, Bates uses `bcrypt` but I can't use it because we create the password hash a different way plus I think that's for the password confirmation magic only). In any case this should not affect the form validation should it?

Any theories or ideas are welcome here, I'm going crazy. I'm about to write some crappy javascript to do it by hand which would be awful and would probably take me a week, I don't do javascript ;)

Thanks.

**Edit**

Per Rachid's request, here are the `new` and `create` actions:

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    #failsafe for failing form validation
    unless params[:passwordHash].present?
      redirect_to new_user_path, :notice => 'User or password cannot be blank' 
    else
      password_and_salt = User.hash_password(params[:passwordHash])
      hashed_password = password_and_salt[:password]
      user_salt = password_and_salt[:salt]
      @user = User.new(:user => params[:user], :passwordHash => hashed_password, :salt => user_salt)
      if @user.save
        session[:user_id] = @user.id
        redirect_to session[:item_to_edit]
      else
        redirect_to new_user_path, :notice => "User already exists, please pick another one"
      end
    end
  end
```

**Edit 2**

I've rewritten the `create` method based on the first answer, but still getting an error:

```
def create
    respond_to do |format|
      if params[:passwordHash].present? && params[:user].present? 
        password_and_salt = User.hash_password(params[:passwordHash])
        hashed_password = password_and_salt[:password]
        user_salt = password_and_salt[:salt]
        @user = User.new(:user => params[:user], :passwordHash => hashed_password, :salt => user_salt, :online_user => 1 )
        if @user.save
          session[:user_id] = @user.id
          redirect_to session[:item_to_edit]
        else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      else
          format.html { render :action => "new" }
          format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The error is `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class` for this line:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
```

Obviously the `@user = User.new` is not making it back to the form. At this point I'm a little confused as to how I should write the `create` method for it to work properly and show the error messages. But I feel I'm closer :)

@misha, here is the `update` controller action, it's just pretty standard scaffolding:

```
def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        if session[:return_to]
          format.html { redirect_to session[:return_to], :notice => 'User was successfully updated.' }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to users_path, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.' }
        end

        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: please show us the related controllers (new, create actions)

Comment: @RachidAlMaach, I've just updated the question with the info you requested, hope that helps determine the error, thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what actually goes wrong. What do you expect to happen that does not happen? And could you show the update controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all what you assume here is incorrect:

> What happens is the `users#create` action being invoked after submitting
>   the form with empty values (which should not be possible). Of course I
>   get an error because the passwordHash is empty.

It is possible that `users#create` is invoked and actually it *should* happen. It is in the create action where you handle this stuff. I think your problem is the fact that you do a redirect if the `@user` is not saved. You should render the view again, so the error messages can be displayed.

So instead of:

```
redirect_to new_user_path, :notice => "User already exists, please pick another one"
```

Try:

```
render :action => 'new'
```

**Edit based on your comment:**

When validation fails Rails populates `@user.errors` automatically. You don't have to do anything in the controller (i.e. your create action)! All you have to do is [display the errors in `@user.errors` in your view](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-the-view).

**About the error you are getting now:**

The reason you are getting the error is that `@user` is not set. You have to rewrite your `create` method to something like this:

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    if params[:user][:passwordHash].present?
      password_and_salt = User.hash_password(params[:user][:passwordHash])
      hashed_password = password_and_salt[:password]
      user_salt = password_and_salt[:salt]
    end

    @user = User.new(params[:user].merge({:passwordHash => hashed_password, :salt => user_salt, :online_user => 1}))

    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to session[:item_to_edit]
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, I'm confused. The update action doesn't have anything in the way of messages yet I do get a message saying the user name can't be blank when there is none. Here, with your change, I do get sent back to the user creation page, but no error messages. What am I missing? Ah, I think it's the `format.json { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }` equivalent that I need in `create` for it to show the errors? Could you help me write that for the `create` method? See edit in original question.

Comment: Where is the original question? When validation fails Rails populates `@user.errors` automatically. You don't have to do *anything* in the controller (i.e. your create action)! All you have to do is display the errors in `@user.errors` in your view.

Comment: Sorry, took me a while to edit the original question, all the info should now be there.

Comment: The link I added in my edit explains how to display errors in your view.

Comment: Ok, I'm reading the link, but based on the `update` action I should be able to get the same functionality with the `create` action right? So where is the error? In the `update` action, when I try to submit a form with no user, I immediately get an inline error in red saying `can't be blank`. That's what I expect to happen in the `create` action as well.

Comment: I updated my answer. This should get rid of the `undefined method 'model_name' for NilClass:Class` error. If you edit your create action like I suggest in my edit, it should work the same as with the update action.

Comment: let's move to chat so we don't get yelled at. Your last edit produces the exact same error I had before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10849/discussion-between-kakubei-and-mischa)